# Array with whether if an array is ascending or not ascending

Tags: c++, arrays

So the question is to figure out whether the array is ascending or not ascending meaning that if the array is 2,3,4,6 it would display yes it is ascending, if it is 3,2,5,6 it would display no not ascending.

I'm cant seem to get the program to display a 0 which mean not ascending and I Know the issue is somewhere in the for loop or if statement but I don't know how to fix it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ascending(int x[], int npts);

int main()
{
    int number[10];
    int num;
    cout<<"How many numbers would you like to enter? (max = 10) ";
    cin>>num;

    for(int i = 0; i<num; i++)
    {
         cout<<"Enter number ";
         cin>>number[i];


    }
    int asc = ascending(number, num);

    cout<<asc;
}

int ascending(int x[], int n)
{
   int count  = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++)
   {
      if(x[i]<x[i + 1])
        count++;

      if(count <= n - 1)
        return 1;
      else
        return 0; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Check your braces. Stepping through the code with a debugger would also help.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the ascending function, you're returning 1 after the first iteration.  In order to determine if the sequence of numbers is ascending, you must iterate through all of them. However,if you find a number that's not ascending at any time, then you can return 0 right away. If you safely iterate through all them without returning 0, than you know the sequence is ascending

```
int ascending(int x[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if(x[i]>=x[i + 1])
            return 0
    }
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Josh, you are returning zero in all cases. You might want to correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
int ascending(int x[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    Do
    {
        if(x[i]> x[i + 1])
        return 0;
        i++;
    } while (i < n-1);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.